# Shared-Key Signature

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, digital-signature, encryption-symmetric

I know that most uses of cryptographic signatures are with public/private keys, but I need to sign information using a pre-shared key. 
I know I can just encrypt the data, but I prefer signing it..

Is it possible in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) is the usual shared key signing algorithm, and it is doable in c#

[How to generate HMAC-SHA1 in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067751/how-to-generate-hmac-sha1-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

there are plenty of schemes (involving HMAC) to perform message signature with symmetric (pre-shared) key material.

possible duplicate:

[Using symmetric key (AES -128) to sign and verify a message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299768/using-symmetric-key-aes-128-to-sign-and-verify-a-message)

Comment: Thanks. Close question, but I asked for C# implementation, while he asked for Java - So I don't believe it's a duplicate.